# Laravel custom error taking too long to response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Laravel Framework** 8.48.0 
**PHP** 7.4.18 
**Local Environment:** Xampp, Windows10

I am developing RESTful API using Laravel 8. I have written some logic inside the `register()` method to make the error response better and more straightforward. Everything is working perfectly. But the problem is when Laravel detects an exception that doesn't fall any of this logic and `APP_DEBUG=true`, this piece of code start executing and takes too long to respond; it says execution timeout. If I clean the `register()` method, it shows an exception within 1 or 2 secs. What's wrong with my code?

I want a better and more precise error response + when `APP_DEBUG=true` quickly shows an error exception.

I think this is the culprit.

```
if (env('APP_DEBUG', false)) {
  return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

**Handler.php**

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    use ApiResponser;

    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];
    
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];
    
    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (Exception $exception, $request) {
            if ($request->wantsJson()) {

                if ($exception instanceof HttpException) {
                    $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
                    $message = Response::$statusTexts[$code];

                    return $this->errorResponse($message, $code);
                }

                if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                    return $this->errorResponse($exception->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
                }

                if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
                    dd('authorization exception');
                    return $this->errorResponse($exception->getMessage(), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
                }

                if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
                    $errors = $exception->validator->errors()->getMessages();

                    return $this->errorResponse($errors, Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
                }
                
                if (env('APP_DEBUG', false)) {
                    return parent::render($request, $exception);
                }

                return $this->errorResponse('Unexpected error occurred. Please contact your administrator for help.', Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        });
    }
}
```